# How to calculate the alpha stable distribution of first order using R?

Tags: r, statistics

Can anyone let me know how I can calculate the alpha stable distribution of first order in R.

Comment: Is [this](http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/fBasics/html/013A-StableDistribution.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: @plannapus I have already went through this packages but I guess in that it is not mentioned how to calculate alpha stable distribution of 1st order. I have gone through other packages also like stabledist..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with this family of distributions: what do you mean by "first-order"? None of the references on stable distributions I found (granting that I just did a quick search) seem to mention that.

Comment: As a general piece of advice on using StackOverflow, try to be very specific when you ask a question by including what you already tried and why do you think it didn't work, for instance.

Comment: @plannapus You are right but problem is that even I don't know what is "First Order", so I posted this question in hope that may someone have an idea about this....anyways thanks for your response.

Comment: Maybe you can ask first on [stats.SE] what could be an alpha-stable distribution of first oder. Additionnaly, [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8515/the-positive-stable-distribution-in-r) gives a few example on how to calculate stable distributions using package `fBasics`.